# how to Separate Files Classes in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am new C++ and I have a question about separate files classes in Xcode. I did write a program trying to lean class, but I got an error. Could anyone teach me how to do that right ?

I include the program that I tried below

**this is the (main CCP):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.h"


using namespace std;


int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
{

    bassam bo;
    bo.bassamfunction();  

}
```

**this is the (.h) :**

```
#ifndef __try_some_concspte__hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh__
#define __try_some_concspte__hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh__

#include <iostream>


class bassam{
public:
    void bassamfunction();

};

#endif /* defined(__try_some_concspte__hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh__) */
```

**this is the (CCP):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.h"
using namespace std;



 bassam::bassamfunction()
{
    cout << " heloo I am here "<< endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `bassam::bassamfunction()` has no return type in the .cpp file. This should be changed to `void bassam::bassamfunction()`.